# Starting Visual Studio as a HIGH priority process?

Tags: windows, command-line

I created a shortcut pointing to `cmd /c "start /high c:\windows\notepad.exe"` so it starts off the notepad process as a high priority process but this doesn't seem to work for the path

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Do not do this. Either 1) your machine will slow to a halt if you get runaway processing in VS (which does happen), 2) Visual Studio will manage its own thread priority. Instead you should lower the priority of the task(s), if any, that are interfering with it, or report the issue at connect.microsoft.com if you have identified a reproducible performance problem.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to quote the entire command in a string like you are doing, also, start has a "bug", if the path has quotes, you must use a pair of empty quotes first to set the "title".

So, your command should look like:

```
cmd /c start "" /high "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

Answer (score 2):

A process can control its own priority, so my guess is that VS will revert back to the normal priority even if you started it at a higher priority.

Answer (score 2):

Create a bat file. Type this in the file:

```
c:
cd\
cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE"
start /high devenv.exe
```

run it. This will open devenv with high priority. (Elevate the bat file in Vista)

Comment: Man, sometimes its right in front of your face and you can't see it :)

Comment: Something like this should be a one liner, this is overkill