# running program in high priority -> does not log anymore

Tags: logging, visual-studio-2010, c

I have a project in visual C 2010 that needs real-time timing in high priority to eliminate stuff like hard disk maintenance and stuff.

I ran the .exe file of my project using `start "" /high & start "" /realtime`. (described here: [Starting Visual Studio as a HIGH priority process?](https://superuser.com/questions/31802/starting-visual-studio-as-a-high-priority-process))

However, in the program I log the elapsed time and several other things, and running it this way stops the program updating the log files?

Note, for visual C, I found the .exe file in the debug folder with it's own separate set of log files.

Comment: Where are you typing that command?

Comment: windows command line. cmd

Comment: And where is the path to the executable you want to start? In the original thread I can see `start "" SomeProgram.exe /high` and there's no EXE path in your example.

Comment: No, that was just reference. My exact path would be something like this: start "" /high C:\Users\Sam\.....\project.exe. Note it does run, it just doesn't log

Comment: Have you checked the directory which is active in `cmd` when you type that command? Can programs write to it? Try with a writable directory.

Comment: gronostaj! thanks a mil! The folder I was running it in was read-only no matter what I set it to. I moved the contents to a new folder elsewhere and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

sheepish: the visual C debug folder was read-only. Move contents to new folder elsewhere. Thanks gronostaj.

note: if visual C does not compile after playing around with high priority, deleting the "program debug database" worked for me.